# is there a bug in repeat attribute of framer/motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have tried a couple of times running the code below, both locally and on codesandbox.
The repeat animation of h1 just doesn't work, is there anything wrong with my code or is it a bug of repeat attribute for motion?

```js
import React from "react";

import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  return (
    <motion.div>
      <motion.h1
        initial={{ y: -200 }}
        animate={{ y: -10 }}
        transition={{ repeat: Infinity, duration: 2 }}
      >
        Test
      </motion.h1>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Check the code on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-scale-correction-forked-lbwcz?file=/src/App.js:0-984)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>It's a problem with your CSS, I guess.</del> I created an empty project: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-sanne-kd5cl?file=/src/index.js.

And it works just fine.

I just copy-pasted one by one in an empty project. The fork doesn't work. Please check out the live demo: https://kd5cl.csb.app/

**It's about `framer-motion` package. `Upgrade` it to the latest or `4.1.17`, currently you are using `2.0.0`**

Comment: Could you locate the css issue please, at the moment, I can't see any difference between your Codesandbox and mine

Comment: @LittleTeemo It's about framer-motion package. Upgrade it to the latest or 4.1.17, currently you are using 2.0.0, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have upgrade framer-motion and react relative packages. Now the issue is solved.